# Docker build is taking too much time?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm","run","dev"]
```

Every time I run the build command , it downloads from node image as instructed at first line.But I thought I was cached to make the image building faster. The total time it takes is like 600+ seconds. Is there a way to make the build proccess faster?

Comment: What commands are you running to rebuild the image?  Do you also need to `COPY package-lock.json` into the image?

Comment: @DavidMaze then he should use a `RUN npm ci` instead. But yes, it would be cleaner if he adds that. ^^

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a tag. Otherwise docker can't know where it can find the related cache.

```bash
docker build -t yourImageName:yourTag .
```

[See also this for more informations](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/docker-cache-tutorial/#:%7E:text=Docker%27s%20build%2Dcache%20is%20a,rebuilding%20from%20a%20certain%20step.)